# OCR works fine on real android device but it does not work on android emulator

Tags: java, android, tess-two

i am developing a simple text recognition android app (OCR) using TessBaseApi. it consists of 2 buttons . one button is used to upload an image from gallery and set it to an imageview(image that contains some text ) and the second button returns recognized text/string  in that image. Everything works fine when i run this app on my real device(samsung galaxy note 4 ). but when i run this app on android studio's emulator  image uploads fine from gallery but text does not recognize from it.my app does not  throws any exception or error. i am using Android Studio 2.3 with the virtual device "Nexus 5X API 22".  this is my code Thanks

```
package com.textrecognition.nasir.textrecognitiondemo;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import static android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button upload;
    Button txtRecog;
    ImageView imgView;

    TextView txt;
    Uri chosenImageURI;
    ProgressDialog progress;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView);


        txtRecog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        txt.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());


        upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            txt.setText("Text will shown here");
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), 100);

            }
        });
        txtRecog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               txtRecog.setClickable(false);
                progress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this) ;
                progress.setMessage("Processing");
                progress.show();
               makeDirectory(); // directories will be made and language files will be copied

            }
        });

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            askPermissions(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 100);
        }
    }

    public void makeDirectory() {

        String dirPathSDCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/TessrectFolder/";
        String languageFileDir = "tessData";
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,dirPathSDCard , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        try {
            File dir = new File(dirPathSDCard + languageFileDir);
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, dir.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (!dir.exists()){
                if (!dir.mkdirs())
                {
                    Log.e("Directory Creation Log", "Could not create directories");
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Directory Creation Log", "Directory already available");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        copyLanguageFileFromAssetsToSDCard(dirPathSDCard, languageFileDir);
        recognizeText(chosenImageURI, dirPathSDCard);
    }

    public void copyLanguageFileFromAssetsToSDCard(String mainPath, String languageFileDir) {
       // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Control reached here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            String fileList[] = getAssets().list(languageFileDir);
           // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + fileList.length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           String str = "";
           for(String fileName : fileList) {
          String pathToDataFile = mainPath + languageFileDir + "/" + fileName;
           if (!(new File(pathToDataFile)).exists()) {

                   InputStream in = getAssets().open(languageFileDir + "/" + fileName);

                   OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pathToDataFile);

                   // Transfer bytes from in to out
                   byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                   int len;

                   while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                       out.write(buf, 0, len);
                   }
                   in.close();
                   out.close();
           }
       }}catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selectedImage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            chosenImageURI = Uri.fromFile(new File(picturePath));
            //chosenImageURI = selectedImage;
            cursor.close();
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(selectedImage).fit()
                    .into(imgView);



        }
    }

    public void recognizeText (Uri imgUri, String data_path){
            try{
               BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 4;
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgUri.getPath(), options);
                TessBaseAPI tessApi = new TessBaseAPI();

                tessApi.init(data_path, "eng");

                tessApi.setImage(bitmap);
                String returnedText = "no text found";
                returnedText = tessApi.getUTF8Text();
                txt.setText(returnedText);
                tessApi.end();
                txtRecog.setClickable(true);
                progress.dismiss();


            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }


    private void askPermissions(String permissionDetail, int requestCode)
    {
       if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permissionDetail) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permissionDetail}, requestCode);
    } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Required Permisssions already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch(requestCode){
            case 100:
                if(grantResults.length > 0  && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Required Permisssions granted",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Required Permisssions denied",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without any code, we have no way of telling for sure.  Although my guess would be than an OCR library is probably implemented in C or C++, and you probably don't have the right ABI compiled in the library

Comment: i am not using native code for it. i added the following statemnt to the dependencies section of the gradle file. now i can makeTessBaseApi object

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        compile 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:5.4.1'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    })

Comment: That doesn't mean the library itself doesn't use native code.  I would be VERY surprised to see image processing done in Java.

Comment: And a quick check-  yes, Tesseract is written in C++.  So make sure you have the correct ABI.  Generally x86-64 is what's missing, so running a 32 bit simulator might fix it without getting the correct .so file

Comment: YOu can even see the last checkin to their github 15 days ago labeled "Don't build 64-bit ABIs by default"

Comment: thanks for your help. but i am wondering why does it work fine on real device but does not on emulator .

Comment: Because you're running an x86-64 emulator, and you aren't building x86-64 C libraries.  The ABI of your emulator and the library have to match.  They may be building x86-32 binaries (in which case a 32 bit emulator will work), or they may only be building ARM (in which case you'd need an ARM device, which pretty much means just phones unless you have a very rare ARM desktop device).

Comment: thank alot for all this explanation. i make a try on emulator  x86-32